# How to get response from api?

Tags: magento-1.9, api, rest-api

I want to get response from **API**.

```
    function curlExec($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $obj = json_decode($result);
    $code = $obj[0]->errormessage;
    if($code == "Success"){
        echo "work";
        exit;
    }else{
        echo "not";
        exit;
    }

}
```

[image]

I am used above code but its return  **NULL** value.

Comment: use `echo $obj->errorcode;`

Comment: I have try this but not any output display.

Comment: can share the output of `var_dump($obj);`

Comment: its display blank page when i hit directly url on browser its show above response.

Comment: {"ErrorCode":"000","ErrorMessage":"Success","JobId":"381a8090-b230-42fa-ac04-157cc2142bfa","MessageData":[{"MobileNumber":"919898xxxxxx ","MessageParts":[{"MessageId": "919898xxxxxx -67e3765cdf034f438a432eacb88d0c14","MessagePartId":1,"MessageText":"test message"}]}]}

Comment: output of this `var_dump($result)`?

Comment: var_dump($result) its display blank. its display when i hit directly on this url. http://globalplsms.in/vendorsms/pushsms.aspx?user=abc&password=xyz&msisdn=919898xxxxxx&sid=SenderId&msg=test%20message&fl=0&gwid=2

Comment: try `echo $obj[0]->errorcode;`

Comment: every time display "NOT".     $code = $obj[0]->errorcode;
  if($code == 000){
   echo "work";
   exit;
  }else{
   echo "not";
   exit;
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below code

```
 $code = $obj[0]->ErrorCode; 
 if($code == 000){ echo "work"; exit; 
 }else{ echo "not"; exit; }
```

sample code for curl follow this

```
$ch = curl_init();

        // set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "url_here");

        //return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        // $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$result=(json_decode($output));

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I have call this on order placed event. any issue with this???

Comment: which event you are using?

Comment: checkout_onepage_controller_success_action_handler

Comment: no there will be no issue with that.

Comment: I don't know what is problem. cant able to get response from API.

Comment: added the sample code too..

Comment: check updated question

Comment: try `echo $obj->ErrorMessage;` or `$obj[0]->ErrorMessage`

Comment: try both but display blank page.

Comment: how to check api call successfully or not i think url cant able to touch server

Comment: read the documentation of api what are you missing can't help their..

Comment: Hey Here, come error HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.

Comment: This error come, when your curl url contains white spaces. you have to encode url for remove white space.  `url_encode($url)`

Comment: it's `urlencode($url);` not url_endoce

Comment: Thanks for your help. simple my mistake. i have directly place url without urlencode. Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Finally Got solution :

```
function curlExec($url) {
        $json = file_get_contents($url);
        $json = json_decode($json);
        $code = $json->ErrorCode;
    }
```